# Why is memory leak size is bigger than memory size allocated to the item?

Tags: c++

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct Resource{
    int fee;  // 4 bytes
};

class MyClass {
    public:
    MyClass( string teacher, Resource * res ) : 
    teacher_(teacher),
    res_(res) { }
     ~MyClass() { 
        // delete res_; // cause indirect leak
    }  
    private:
    string teacher_;
    Resource * res_;
};

int main(){
    Resource * res = new Resource;
    res->fee=100;
    cout<<"size of Resource "<<sizeof(res)<<endl;
    MyClass * cl = new MyClass("Tom", res);  
    cl = new MyClass ("Joh", res);
    cout<<"size of My Class "<<sizeof(cl)<<endl;
    delete cl;
}
```

Address Sanitizer returns the following error:

```
size of Resource 8
size of My Class 8
Program stderr

=================================================================
==1==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 40 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f863ac55518 in operator new(unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdb518) (BuildId: 5ce9c09d3612315d01d50bcaafaea176e7ddab77)
    #1 0x402445 in main /app/example.cpp:25
    #2 0x7f863a5d3082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)

Indirect leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f863ac55518 in operator new(unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdb518) (BuildId: 5ce9c09d3612315d01d50bcaafaea176e7ddab77)
    #1 0x4023c4 in main /app/example.cpp:22
    #2 0x7f863a5d3082 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x24082) (BuildId: 1878e6b475720c7c51969e69ab2d276fae6d1dee)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 44 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

- **indirect leak** has the size of 4 bytes. I think that is the memory chunk allocated to int value of the struct `Resource`.
- **direct leak** however has the size of 40 bytes. The size is neither sum of MyClass (size 8) and struct Resource (size 8).

Why is direct leak so big?

Comment: "The size is neither sum of MyClass (size 8)" - in your own words, why do you think `MyClass` should have that size? Did you try to check it, for example by using `sizeof(MyClass)`? I notice that each `MyClass` instance will have a `private: string teacher_;`. How many bytes do you think it takes for that? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I printed out the size of `MyClass` and `Resource` using sizeof operator.

Comment: Are you sure you printed out `sizeof(MyClass)` and not a pointer to it? No way is `sizeof(MyClass)` 8 but a pointer to it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong about `sizeof`. `cl` is a pointer and `sizeof(cl)` is size of a pointer, which is 8bytes on most 64-bit platforms. You should use `sizeof(MyClass)` or `sizeof(*cl)` to get the object size.

`MyClass` has two data members, commonly `std::string` in gcc implementation costs 32bytes for short strings (you can search `short string optimization` for more details), and `Resource *` costs 8bytes. Hence `sizeof(MyClass)` is 40bytes, which is the direct leak size.

Comment: Mighty appreciation! So the leak size is indeed the size of MyClass, and indirect leak is the size of Resource. The correct way to print out the size should be as you answered.